# Form Submit on Toggle click

Tags: javascript, php, html, wordpress

I am working on a plugin for my WordPress site but I am stuck on this one part. I have managed to create a form that when clicked, changes the prices on the website (showing with and without VAT)*. The problem I am having is that I want it to be a toggle not two buttons but I cannot seem to find the right code anywhere. I have found code that creates a toggle but it doesn't submit the form when pressed.

I want it to submit the form when clicked and stay clicked until the user clicks it again.I am sure you can do this with JavaScript but I am not sure on how.

I am probably missing something obvious but I just cannot seem to work this one out.

Any help would be greatly appreciated

- Please note I understand that this would be not recommended for an e-commerce site but the site is a lead generator.

example of the HTML with two buttons not a toggle

```
<form action="" method="post">
<input type="submit" name="personal" value="personal">
<input type="submit" name="business" value="business">
</form><br>
```

example of PHP

```
function adds_personal_toggle() {
if (isset($_POST["personal"])) {

$_SESSION['personal'] = 'personal';

}

if (isset($_POST["business"])) {

unset($_SESSION["personal"]);

}

}
```

Comment: It might be nice to add relevant HTML and whatever code you have so far, even if it fails to do what you are wanting

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have added the code in there now.

Answer (score 0):

I think a single button is sufficient to achieve whatever you are looking for. Set the required value in request attribute.

```
$_REQUEST["key"] = "Personal" or "Business";
if ($_REQUEST["key"] is "Personal") {        
    // button generation code for Personal;
}

if ($_REQUEST["key"] is "Business") {   
    // button generation code for Business;        
}
```

Also you can manipulate your action inside form tag with the help of above if statements.

```
action="php_file.php?type=Personal or Business"
```

Proper usage of if statements will generate only one button with "Personal" or "Business" as per your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer and thought I would share if anyone had similar problems.

if you use

```
<input type="checkbox" value="personal" name="personal" onchange="document.getElementById('INSERT FORM ID HERE').submit()" <?php echo $checked; ?> ></input>
```

it will submit the form when the checkbox is clicked. Also if you add

```
$checked = 'checked';
```

Into the if statement in the PHP file, the toggle will stay checked once the it has been selected.

Hope that helps someone.

Answer (score -1):

in your function toggle button call your update fuction

Example given below:

```js
    function Toggle() {
     //your code here for toggle
     Update()
    }

    function Update() {
    // your code for update
    }
```